# Java Servlet Hosting

Tags: java, servlets, hosting

I want to find a hosting service for a small Java servlet (running on Tomcat, no database required). Any suggestions or anything I need to be careful about? Also: The only thing I need to upload to the hosting service is the .war file?

Comment: You say that it's running on tomcat and you need hosting =?

Comment: just google for "tomcat web hosting"

Comment: I'm developing/running it locally, I won't run the machine 24/7

Answer (score 1):

If its just a war then eatj is good.

Update:
In Feb, 2018 Amazon AWS is the best.

Comment: Tried signing up for their trial option - and there appeared a jsp exception lol.